# Extract interface missing from Quick Actions and Refactorings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

I have installed VS2017 Enterprise 15.9.11 on a new laptop with latest resharper and when I click Ctrl + . on a class type the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu opens but extract interface is missing.

Any idea why it is not showing?

Comment: Anyone please can help?

Comment: I just had the same issue and realised it was because none of the methods were public :O

Comment: @fruitbatinshades I'd accept that if it was an answer! :facepalm:

Comment: if all methods are non-static and public, and Ctrl + . still not working, you can use Ctrl + R + I to extract interface.

Answer (score -1):

If all the methods in the class are static, you can't use an Interface, so it won't display that option.  Just get rid of all static methods - they're a nuisance and a bad idea anyway.